# Display php created table from jquery code - datatables drill down rows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable that I am attempting to put drill-downs into based on the output of a php file, but I am having a few issues I can't seem to figure out.  I am using http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows as a guide.  So far this is my code:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("tr").live("click", function(){
        var nTr = this;
        var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);
        //oTable = my datatable 
        var oData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        if(i === -1) {
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
            //THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING A LITTLE LOST
            //I WANT THE VALUE OF response.details TO BE STORED IN nDetailsRow
            //oData.url is a mDataProp stored in the datatable row that contains the PHP link (this works okay)
            var nDetailsRow = $.get(oData.url, function(response) {
                //I don't really understand exactly what this is doing... but response.details is what I want to display from PHP
                oTable.fnOpen(nTr, response.details, 'details');
                });
            //THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK CORRECTLY BECAUSE nDetailsRow IS NOT WHAT I WANT IT TO BE 
            $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
            anOpen.push(nTr);

        else {
        ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP
    $tableOut = '<div class="innerDetails">
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">
                        <tr><td>Test Cell:</td><td>This is a test</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>';

    $data = array();
    $data['details'] = $tableOut;

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I feel like I am almost there, but I don't quite understand the ajax `$.get` and am not sure if I am actually getting the JSON correctly from the PHP file.  I also don't quite understand how to store that JSON in the active jquery code.  Any ideas on how to accomplish these tasks and how to get my drill-down to display the PHP JSON data `response.details`?

Comment: Not related to the question, but don't use live. It is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead. It is worth mentioning here simply because you are working on it and it is an easy fix ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I changed it to `$(document).on("click", "tr", function(){` in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out almost immediately after posting, I needed to use `$.getJSON` and include the last two lines inside that function.  I am now using the following code which appears to work correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "tr", function(){
        var nTr = this;
        var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);
        //oTable = my datatable & oData.url is the mDataProp link to the PHP page
        var oData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        if(i === -1) {
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');           
            $.get(oData.url, function(response) {
                oTable.fnOpen(nTr, response.details, 'details');
                $('div.innerDetails', response.details).slideDown();
                anOpen.push(nTr);
                });     

        else {
        ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

Edit: Added/changed code from suggestions

Comment: Yes, might as well let jQuery handle the JSON rather than doing `eval` yourself. FWIW, it will also treat the response as JSON if you use `$.get(..., 'json')` or if you set a `Content-type: application/json` header in your PHP script.

Comment: @Das.Rot Do you have any idea about [How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991927/how-to-create-jquery-datatable-drill-down-rows) Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("tr").live("click", function(){
        var nTr = this;
        var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);
        //oTable = my datatable 
        var oData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        if(i === -1) {
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
            //THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING A LITTLE LOST
            //I WANT THE VALUE OF response.details TO BE STORED IN nDetailsRow
            //oData.url is a mDataProp stored in the datatable row that contains the PHP link (this works okay)
            var nDetailsRow = $.get(oData.url, function(response) {
                try{
                    eval(response);
                    delete response;
                  //I don't really understand exactly what this is doing... but response.details is what I want to display from PHP
                    oTable.fnOpen(nTr, req.details, 'details');
                }catch(e){
                    // error
                }
            });
            //THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK CORRECTLY BECAUSE nDetailsRow IS NOT WHAT I WANT IT TO BE 
            $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
            anOpen.push(nTr);

        else {
        ...
        }
    }
</script>

PHP:

var req = { details : '<?php echo str_replace('%', '\\x', urlencode('
<div class="innerDetails">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">
        <tr>
            <td>Test Cell:</td>
            <td>This is a test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>')); ?>' };
```

Comment: would you mind explaining what is going on with the `eval(response)` and `delete response`?  Will this save the response into the var `nDetailsRow`?

Comment: I apologize, I tested it out and that's exactly what it does. Thanks!

Comment: @e-info128 Do you have any idea about [How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991927/how-to-create-jquery-datatable-drill-down-rows) Thanks in advance...